# An unknown msg is being displayed everytime on some selected sites.!

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

When ever I open some video sites like Hotstar. A big icon of Google Chrome appears and it say some System error occurred and it literally pushes us to download a file... After its download my antivirus ( 360Antivirus) shows tht it's a Trojan file downloaded! How can disable it frm coming!? Any idea abt it?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect one of two things: 1) you've not got an adblocker running, or 2) you've got something already installed that is pulling this file down and attempting to social-engineer an install.

Go into your Chrome download history, and look at the location where the file originated (it'll be the line under the filename).  Then, block that domain, either by adding it to Norton 360's naughty list, or by aliasing it to 127.0.0.1 in windows/drivers/etc/host.

Comment: Thank you for your support! Just now I realised tht its not just a ad but it's a page... Adblock could just block some part of it... But after blocking it, it still come up wid a blank page then.. And I have searched for tht file, but I didn't find it! A discription of tht ad - "SECURITY ERROR: This website requires Google Chrome security plugin. 'Install button'. There are false antivirus alarms,. We recommend temporarily disable antivirus software"

Comment: This is definitely a social-engineer attempt.  If it's only showing up in Chrome, then you may have a rogue extension throwing it at you. Time to think about which extensions were installed just prior to this happening, and disable them. Test each individually. The one that 'allows' the page is the culprit... kill it with fire. Or, if only certain sites show it to you... don't visit those sites.